# how to setup app.yaml for static directory indexing

Tags: app.yaml

How can I setup any number of directories with nesting to use a given index file (eg index.html) as the default response, with or without the trailing slash? On Google App Engine using the `app.yaml` configuration file.

for example:

- `url path requested` => response
- `/content/` => /content/index.html (trailing slash for directory)
- `/other/path` => /other/path/index.html (no trailing slash)

Answer (score 0):

toward the end of `app.yaml` use broad capturing with optional trailing slash and include the `require_matching_file` flag at the end of that block

```
- url: /(.+)/?$
  static_files: www/\1/index.html
  upload: www/(.+)/index.html
  require_matching_file: true
```